# croogo error plugin search

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I download a search plugin from http://www.cakedc.com/downloads. and I used cakephp/croogo 1.4.3.

I renamed the search plugin 'Search' and I download in `app/Plugin/`.

in my controller:

```
public $name = 'MovementsRouts';
public $components = array('Search.Prg');
public $presetVars = array(
    array('field' => 'name', 'type' => 'value'),
    array('field' => 'status', 'type' => 'value'),
);

    public function admin_index_route() {

            $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Movement Taxi route'));

            $this->MovementsRout->recursive = 0;

             $this->Prg->commonProcess();

            $this->paginate = array(

                'MovementsRout' => array(
                  'conditions' => $this->MovementsRout->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs),
                    //'conditions' => array('MovementsRout.type_mvt ='=>'route_taxi'),

                    //'fields'=>array('id','description','title','support_count','oppose_count','user_id','created'),

                    'limit' => 5,

                    //'paramType' => 'querystring'

            ));

            $this->set('movementsRouts', $this->paginate());



        }
```

in my model:public

```
$name = 'MovementsRouts';    
public $components = array('Search.Prg');

public $presetVars = array(
    array('field' => 'name', 'type' => 'value'),
    array('field' => 'status', 'type' => 'value'),
);
```

in my view `index_route.ctp`:

```
<div><?php
        echo $this->Form->create('MovementsRout', array(
            'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'index'), $this->params['pass'])
            ));
        echo $this->Form->input('name', array('div' => false, 'empty' => true)); // empty creates blank option.
                echo $this->Form->input('status', array('label' => 'Status', 'options' => $statuses));
        echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
        echo $this->Form->end();
    ?>
        </div>
```

and I add in `config/bootstrap`:

```
CakePlugin::load('Search');
```

> ERROR DISPLAY :  **Fatal error: Class 'Hash' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wfs\app\Plugin\Search\Controller\Component\PrgComponent.php on line 85**

IN line 85 in app\Plugin\Search\Controller\Component\PrgComponent.php:

```
$this->_defaults = **Hash**::merge($this->_defaults, array(
            'commonProcess' => (array)Configure::read('Search.Prg.commonProcess'),
            'presetForm' => (array)Configure::read('Search.Prg.presetForm'),
        ), $settings);
    }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: the search plugin nommed Search

Comment: "plugin" is a typo what I mean is that I rennomé the search plugin by Search in the directory "app / plugin /

Comment: I think you haven't understand my point, I'm not looking at the word "plugi" which is obviously meant to be plugin. I asked what is "nommed"? it's not an English word. From the above "rennomé" I guess you meant renamed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mismatch between the cakephp version that Croogo bundles and what the Search plugin expects.  To use Search plugin in Croogo 1.4.3, you need to find out which CakePHP version it's using, and download the correct version of Search plugin for that specific version of CakePHP.

Croogo 1.4.3 is really old, 14 releases behind the current stable. A lot has been improved and version 1.5.x already supports the Search plugin by default. I suggest you upgrade to the latest stable.

Comment: I am trying to install 1.5.8 croogo I made coditiennes steps.
the server displays to install page (i establishment of user and password).
the problem is that after I actually created user I wanted to goto the admin page
hands it to automatically enter the setup page.

Comment: pleaaaaaaaaaaaase any idea to my problem ???Therefore, after completing the installation page I clicked "localhost/croogo1-5-8/admin" but returne the installation page "localhost/croogo-1.5.8/install why why????
I also test croogo 1.5.0 is the same thing.

Comment: There are multitude of reasons an install can fail. This is a different question altogether and without more information, it's difficult to help.  The best advice I can give you are:

- Verify that tables are really created and data inserted.
- Check tmp/logs/error.log.
- Verify that APP/Config/croogo.php, APP/Config/database.php, and APP/Config/settings.json are created.

Comment: I redid the installation again
I want to explain what I do:
First: change database
Secondly: edit croogo.php (Security.salt and Security.cipherSeed)
and I have nothing to setting.json
Now it appears the login page directly, in principle it appears the installation page first

Comment: i can't Install croogo 1.5.8

Comment: what's it is necessary modifications to the file setting.json and coogo.php

Comment: pleaaaaaaase an simple example to search plugin I have a **table** nammed movements_routs and controller nommed MovementsRoutsController and model MovementsRout and folder view nommed MoventsRouts

Comment: please a documentation or simple search plugin exampl pleaaase

Comment: @hello991 Pleeeeeeeeease stop! These are entirely different questions, and it really doesn't fit here on SO if you can't provide proper details that make the problem understandable and reproducable. You're probably better off discussing this in the [**croogo google group**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/croogo).